# highcharts lang.resetZoom doesn't appear to work

Tags: highcharts

I've read the API docs, search the google, but far as I can tell, setting

```
lang: {
  resetZoom: "foo"
}
```

doesn't work. I've localized other keys in lang and they take hold, but not resetZoom or resetZoomTitle. Using Highcharts 4.1.1

Here's a fiddle I modified: http://jsfiddle.net/66fch6t3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        lang: {
            resetZoom: "reset me please"
        },
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            resetZoomButton: {
                theme: {
                    fill: 'white',
                    stroke: 'silver',
                    r: 0,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fill: '#41739D',
                            style: {
                                color: 'white'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This works if you do it through the `Highcharts.setOptions` function. For example:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        resetZoom: "reset me please"
    }
});


$('#container').highcharts({
   ...
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/66fch6t3/1/) for how it looks and works.

If you look at [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.resetZoom) you'll see that `lang` appears under `Highcharts.setOptions({` in the tree structure to the left, and not under `$("#container").highcharts({`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Bad example I gave, but it doesn't quite match what we're doing. We're using the highcharts angular directive, and setting other "lang" options works but not the resetZoom and resetZoomTitle. `    return {
      options: {
        legend: {
          enabled: true
        },
        lang: {
          noData: 'no data',
          resetZoom: 'reset me',
          resetZoomTitle: 'reset title',
          contextButtonTitle: 'context menu'
        },
 ...`

Comment: I see. I would consider editing that into the question in some way (description or tag). I also see that the similar code-segment still works for Highcharts-ng, but knowing nothing about Angular I assume that is a un-Angular way of doing things. I'll still leave the answer in case someone stumbles upon a slightly similar situation.

Comment: Yes, thanks. If anything it's a highcharts-ng issue. Thanks for the help on the workaround.

Comment: You can report this bug on highcharts-ng github.